# No \resourcepack and folder

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I downloaded Minecraft and downloaded 2 resource packs. When I went to the .minecraft folder, there was no \resourcepacks folder. Is this a bug, or because I'm running Windows 8, or what?

Comment: have you gone into settings, gone into resource packs and clicked on the button to open the directory (i think it's titled "open dir")

Comment: Yeah, it says no \resourcepacks still, even after manually searching it myself.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using version before 1.8.1-pre1, game does not generate resourcepacks folder automatically so you have to manually make the folder. It is [fixed in 1.8.1-pre1](https://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/2jbgrt/minecraft_181_prerelease_1/cla42vk):

> Fixed the resource pack folder not automatically being created when starting the game

Answer (score 0):

In the options tab there should be a option called resource packs, if you click on that you should get a screen with a button open resource pack folder, that should get you there.

Answer (score -1):

Try creating the folder yourself and dropping them into the folder. If that doesn't work, are you using an older version where it was /texturepacks instead?

Comment: I'm using 1.8 of Minecraft.